# How to server a react application in apache properly?

Tags: reactjs, linux, apache, ubuntu, server

I am using apache to run a moodle application (PHP), but now I need to add a React app inside this moodle application but when try to start the React app it just shows an empty index.html

I have modified the apache config file to serve react apps like this:

```
<VirtualHost ipserver:443>
        ServerAdmin moodleapp@domain.com
        ServerName moodleapp

        DocumentRoot /var/www/moodleapp
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/upficerror.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/upficaccess.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/aula/moodleapp.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/aula/moodleapp.ca
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/aula/moodleapp.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/moodleapp/>
                Options -Indexes
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/moodleapp/react/build>
            Options -Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.html
            FallbackResource /react/index.html
        </Directory>

        Alias /react /var/www/moodleapp/react/build

        <Location /react>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
        </Location>

        <Directory /var/www/moodleapp/react/src>
            Options -Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /react/src /var/www/moodleapp/react/src

</VirtualHost>
```

And also inside the Rreact app root I have an .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /react/index.html [L]
```

My react app was built with vite and this is the file config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: true,
  }
});
```

Inside the package.json I also added the `"homepage"` like this:

```
"name": "react",
"private": true,
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "commonjs",
"homepage": "/react/",
```

Once started the app with `yarn start` or even using `pm2` I checked the path using `domain/react` or `ip/react`, but it doesn't work. Inspecting the Network in the browser I see that the page is receiving 404 errors from `https://mydomain/@vite/client`, `https://mydomain/src/main.jsx` and `https://mydomain/@react-refresh`, but obviously the path is wrong because `main.jsx` is inside `mydomain/react/src/main.jsx` not `mydomain/src/main.jsx`. I am not sure where the error is.